# CustomRenderer not applying

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

The BackgroundColor property on Xamarin.Forms.Buttons started coloring the entire area assigned to the button instead of just the button, so I started delving into the Custom Renderers in Android to see if I could fix it. The following is the class I created, the .xaml where I use a custom button, and the renderer (it's just supposed to color the button green as a test):

`using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace wcsmobile
{
    public class wcsButton : Button
    {
    }
}`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wcsmobile;assembly=wcsmobile"
    x:Class="wcsmobile.Transfer"
    Title="Transfer">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <local:wcsButton Text="OK" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(wcsButton), typeof(ButtonRenderer))]
namespace wcsmobile.Droid
{
class wcsButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    public wcsButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);
        }
    }
}
}
```

There is no error, but the button stays gray, not green. Putting a breakpoint at the "base.OnElementChanged(e)" doesn't do anything; the breakpoint never gets hit. Both projects are using Xamarin.Forms version 3.1.0.583944.

Anyone with a clue as to why the Custom Renderer doesn't seem to be applying would be very helpful. (Or even an idea as to why BackgroundColor seemed to stop working in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned "both projects" the answer seems obvious: the renderer from project A isn't applied to project B. You have the choice to move it to appropriate project OR move it to a shared project https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=vswin